# Pass object (taken from backend API) from HTML to Typescript using ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm populating a selectpicker with values taken from the backend API:

```
<select class="selectpicker mt-2" data-live-search="true" [(ngModel)]="startingCity">
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city">{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

As you can see I put the "ngModel" in it and what I'm trying to do now is to get selected value in typescript so I would like to pass a whole object - it is the same type of object which populates the selectpicker list with the "*ngFor" directive - but I can't find solution for it.

```
export class TrackComponent implements OnInit {
 cities: any;
 startingCity: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getCities();
   document.getElementById('proceedBtn').addEventListener('click', this.getTracks, false);
  }

  getCities() {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/cities/').subscribe(response => {
    this.cities = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

getTracks() {
   console.log(this.startingCity.id);
 }

}
```

Typescript class looks something like this - as you can see it populates html selectpicker (list) with cities taken from the backend API. I also added event listener for the button so after the click it would call the method getTracks() and get the object's id in the same way as it does with the name in the "{{city.name}}" in html but in typescript.

I'm aware it might be a duplicate question but I didn't find any useful solution and some of the ideas are just so vague for me since I'm newbie on this.

EDIT: In the current state startingCity is not defined - says console error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use ngModel with ngModelChange as follows

```
<select [(ngModel)]="startingCity" (ngModelChange)="getTracks(startingCity,$event.target.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city">
            {{city.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

and in your `getTracks` function console.log arguments

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've managed to pass the argument to the function without event listener but in the end I'm going to need two different parameters in the same time (there will be startingCity and destinationCity - that's why I'd like to have the method without any parameters.

Comment: use this function without arguments, just like this `(ngModelChange)="getTracks()"`.

`getTracks() {
        console.log(this.startingCity);
    }`

`cities = [{id:1, name: "LA"}, {id:2, name: "NY"}];
startingCity; 
` 
 I'm also not define this variable



my console output `{id: 3, name: "LA"}`

I have reproduce your code on my pc and it works fine

Comment: Well it does work, properly calling method and returning the desired id but when I press the "submit" button which is calling the same method it returns error with this.startingCity not defined and I actually need it to be called after the button is clicked, not when the selection was changed.

Comment: as @Mustahsan said fill your variable this.startingCity = this.cities[0]; when you recieve data.

If your submit function init like this `document.getElementById('proceedBtn').addEventListener('click', this.getTracks, false);`, try bind your function to component context like this `document.getElementById('proceedBtn').addEventListener('click', this.getTracks.bind(this), false);`

Comment: This is it actually. Thank you very much! Putting "this.getTracks.bind(this)" does the trick. I've checked it with the code I've started with and it's still the actual solution.

Comment: I was glad to help you )) But why you don't use this way `<button id="proceedBtn" (click)="getTracks()">Submit</button>` ?

Comment: At first I did that but then the method wasn't called properly. After short searching on the internet I've read that it's much wiser to use event listeners instead of direct "(click)" - but it wasn't direct solution for my problem but it accidently solved the issue with not being able to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `startingCity` anywhere in your controller thats why it is causing the issue, also as the data is coming `async` so its better to check that in template as well:

```
<select *ngIf="cities" class="selectpicker mt-2" data-live-search="true" [(ngModel)]="startingCity">
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city">{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.getCities();
  }

 getCities() {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/cities/').subscribe(response => {
    this.cities = response;
    this.startingCity = this.cities[0];
    document.getElementById('proceedBtn').addEventListener('click', this.getTracks, false);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I did the exact thing as you posted and I'm still getting "this.startingCity is undefined" while calling the "getTracks()" method.

Comment: thats because you are calling it before it is initialized, you need to understand that api will return data after sometime but your code will be executed immediately

Comment: I call getTracks() method after clicking the button. Selectpicker is already populated from the same API so it actually got the objects inside "cities" but I still can't get the object back from the selectpicker? I mean what should I do in that case?